# Taking user data from a text box and writing it to a specific json name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am able to succsessfully read the values from my file, I just can't figure out how to write to the specific names.

What I started trying was

```
public void writeCharacter()
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1();
    string homepath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("homepath");
    try
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(homepath + @"\Documents\DnD5e\charactersheet.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

            JsonSerializer jserialize = new JsonSerializer();
            foreach (Control ctrl in f1.Controls)
            {
                if (ctrl.Tag == "CHANGED")
                {
                    jserialize.Serialize(jw, ctrl.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        
        MessageBox.Show(e.Source + "\n\n" + e.Message);
    }
}
```

the only problem is that I can't figure out where the serializer is writing to and I can't figure out how to specify what name it is to write to.

I want to take the input from text boxes (when the text is changed they are given the tag "CHANGED") and depending on which textbox the data comes from I want it written to that specific name. any help is much appreciated!!

my code is all hosted [on git](https://github.com/NathanJ4620/DnD5e)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a `JsonWriter`, you don't need to allocate a `JsonSerializer`. A `JsonWriter` is the lower level mechanism used to write out the JSON:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(homepath + @"\Documents\DnD5e\charactersheet.json",
                                 FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
using (JsonWriter jw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
    jw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

    foreach (Control ctrl in f1.Controls)
    {
        if (ctrl.Tag == "CHANGED")
        {
            jw.WritePropertyName(ctrl.Name);
            jw.WriteValue(ctrl.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

The `JsonWriter` will write via your `StreamWriter`, to the file.

Comment: So, in your example, I'm using the tag to specify the name that I'm writing to?

Comment: @user2712963 In my example, you're using the `ctrl.Tag` as the property name. You can replace it with anything you'd like, like `ctrl.Name`. I changed it to be clear.

Comment: Would the control name (the text box) having the same name as the c# property cause problems. For instance, if I were to call a text box "race" and have a string called "race".

Comment: No, it would simply cause the key value pair to be `"race": "race" `

Comment: What I meant is if I were to have 'public string name;' and also have a text box in my form which had the name of 'name' would that not cause an exception in my code.

Comment: No. Because `Control.Name` isn't a field of your class, it's a field of the `Control` class. Also, fields are case-sensitive. `Name` and `name` aren't the same. But I don't see how that has anything to do with the question?

Comment: Sweet! thank you! I will try this tomorrow when I am fresh! Now I must sleep!!

Comment: @user My answer doesn't help?

Comment: For some reason the if to check the tag isn't triggering. I know that the tag is being changed but it won't trigger.

Comment: How does that relate to the answer though? You asked about writing out a JSON, not about `if` statements not falling through?

Comment: @user2712963 No need to be sorry, just trying to clarify. You can always ask a new question.

Comment: That's what I'll do. Thanks again